# Поиск столбца или строки из единиц

Tags: алгоритм

Дана квадратная марица размера n, которая заполнена нулями и единицами. Цель : найти в матрице или строчку или столбик, который полностью состоит из единиц. Алгоритм должен иметь асимптотическую сложность O(n).

Есть какие нибудь идеи как подойти к решению?

Comment: Имеется в виду матрица `n`x`n`?

Comment: @Harry, ну раз она квадратная, то по-другому никак :)

Comment: Просто у @Vlad было сказано, что проход по всем элементам дает O(n), вот я и удивился и решил уточнить, не число ли элементов n...

Answer (score 1):

Заметим, что любой встреченный нами 0, автоматически выбивает из рассмотрения строку и столбец, на пересечении которых он находится. Поэтому - будем ловить не 1, будем ловить 0.

Движемся по матрице. Только не лобовым перебором, а змейкой:

```
1  2  3  4 
12 13 14 5
11 16 15 6
10 9  8  7
```

Встречая 0, мы должны немедленно запоминать свои координаты в два массива - "плохие строки" и "плохие столбики", после чего, оказываясь на таких строках и столбцах - пропускать их целиком. Помимо этого, мы должны сразу проскакивать вперед до стенки из своих предыдущих витков, потому как данную горизонталь или вертикаль можно считать "плохой".

У нашего путешественника по матрице, помимо координат, есть направление движения - либо горизонтальное, либо вертикальное. Так вот, пропуск надо делать только тогда. когда мы заходим в "горизонтальном режиме" на плохую строку и в "вертикальном режиме" на плохой столбик.

Если наша змейка уперлась лбом в стену или в предыдущий виток - ура, мы нашли нужный столбик или строку.

**Крайние случаи:**

Матрица забита 0 - отловим при первом же проходе по горизонтали, заполнив черный список столбиков.

Матрица забита 1 - отловим на первом же проходе, зарегистрировав целую строку из 1

Comment: "Матрица забита 1 - отловим на первом же проходе, зарегистрировав целую строку из 1" - но ведь надо найти все такие строки, а не одну

Comment: @smellyshovel Нам нужно найти хотя бы 1 строку, а не все.

Comment: А, точно. Не правильно понял.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, при последовательно прохождении сначала по строкам, а затем по столбцам, сложность алгоритма будет O( n^2 ).

Но вы можете исключить ту часть из алгоритма, которая проходит по всем столбцам. Для этого просто надо суммировать значения по столбцам, когда алгоритм будет проходить по каждой строке. В результате если какая-то сумма окажется равной `n`, то следовательно соответствующий столбец состоит из всех единиц.

Для реализации этого подхода понадобится дополнительная память в виде одномерного массива, содержащего `n` элементов.

Comment: Извините, а подробнее можно? просто никак не врублюсь, как при проходе по `n^2` элементам получается сложность O(n)?

Comment: @Harry Что-то когда я говорил о матрицах, я думал об одномерных массивах. Сейчас исправлю.:)

Comment: Вот да.. даже если мы пройдемся только по строкам, то это все равно решение за квадрат.

Comment: @marka_17 Пока ничего другого мне в голову не приходит. Может быть еще кто-нибудь подкинет идею.:) Но в любом случае придется проходить по всем элементам матрицы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, в O(n) в общем случае не верится... Но понятно, что, встретив первый же 0, эту строку и столбец можно выбрасывать из рассмотрения, так что в матрице, где таких строк/столбцов будет немного, и скорость будет повыше.

В теоретическом пределе, *если он один* - как раз O(n) (n проверок на нули по первому значению + n проверок, чтоб убедиться, что там все единицы.

Но в общем случае, не имея какой-то дополнительной информации? не верится.

А откуда дровишки, грубо говоря? Надежда, что такой алгоритм может существовать?

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно извиняюсь, но ввод исходных данных это уже O(n^2), даже если придумать что-то за O(n), все равно с вводом это будем квадрат, ну а без ввода задача не имеет смысла. Может n в задаче это не порядок матрицы, а количество элементов(т.е например матрица 3х3, n = 9)? Тогда логичнее было б.

**UPD**

Ну кстати, можно решить за O(n) если не учитывать ввод матрицы. Заведем массивы x, y длинной n в которых будет содержаться True если строка / столбец полностью из единиц состоит. При вводе матрицы если a[i][j] == 0 то помечаем x[i] = False, y[j] = False. И тогда нам потом останется пройтись по массивам x, y что займет ровно линейное время и найти любой элемент равный True.